# mysqld keeps crashing

Tags: windows, mysql

Mysql kept working normally from many days and suddenly it crashes on all commands. Please help me to solve it.

```
130206 21:03:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 
130206 21:03:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 
130206 21:03:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 
130206 21:03:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3 
130206 21:03:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M 
130206 21:03:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
130206 21:03:03 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda. InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles! 
130206 21:03:03 InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally! InnoDB: Starting crash recovery. InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files... InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite InnoDB: buffer... 
130206 21:03:04 InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start 
130206 21:03:05 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 3480263 
130206 21:03:05 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306 
130206 21:03:05 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0'; 
130206 21:03:05 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'. 
130206 21:03:05 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events 
130206 21:03:05 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '5.5.27'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
130206 21:04:24 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown  
130206 21:04:24 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events 
130206 21:04:24 InnoDB: Starting shutdown... 
130206 21:04:24 InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 3480263 
130206 21:04:24 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Might want to move this to the DBA SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a crash, but a normal shutdown. So there's something/someone killing it.

Comment: I am just trying to drop a database from phpmyadmin and it makes no sense to me. can you help please. The problem is specific to one database rest all are working fine. The database has zero tables, so it literally makes no sense

Comment: That has nothing to do with a database either crashing or shutting down.

Comment: can you please guide as to what could be the root of the problem??? can it be mysql workbench? or netbeans?